# How can Inuyashiki and Hiro hear voices from Earth?

Tags: inuyashiki

In Inuyashiki manga chapter 82

> Inuyashiki was not able to hear the voice of Hiro when they were standing on meteor far from earth in space. So Hiro called Inuyashiki (via some telecommunication mechanism).
>  [image]

Later

> When Hiro was going to blow himself up, he heard the voice of Watanabe Shion. And the same thing happened to Inuyashiki - when he was going to self-destruct he also heard the voices of his family and dog.
>  [image]
>  [image]

How can they hear voices from the earth? Given that they were not able to communicate so Hiro had to call Inuyashiki.

<sub>Anime is still going on and I don't know how they're gonna show these parts.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:
They are very advanced machines, and as we know, they can communicate with all the networks on earth. The phone network doesnt reach the space but they on the space can reach the earth. That is why they even have their phones inside them.
Good luck!